# "Swig to java (Android)": giving No such file or directory Error on generating Swig to Java file

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, swig

I am new to Swig trying to convert a basic C file to java interface using Swig.
I have a compute.i file:

```
%module compute

%inline %{
extern int    gcd(int x, int y);
extern double Foo;
%}
```

and compute.c file:

```
/* A global variable */
double Foo = 3.0;

/* Compute the greatest common divisor of positive integers */
int gcd(int x, int y) {
  int g;
  g = y;
  while (x > 0) {
    g = x;
    x = y % x;
    y = g;
  }
  return g;
}
```

Also a `MainActivity` with basic onCreateView Method. i tried to generate computeJNI.java with following command:

```
swig -java -package com.example.swigbasicproject -outdir src/com/example/swigbasicproject/swig -o jni/compute_wrap.c jni/compute.i
```

but it gives me following error:

```
Unable to open file src/com/example/swigbasicproject/swig/computeJNI.java: No such file or directory
```

What is it that i am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Output directory must already exists before running swig command.

Comment: I have used the following link  http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Android.html , if the file doesn't exist, it should get created.    Also i am little confused how compute_wrap will get created.

Comment: but if directory `-outdir` does not exists, it will return error. I have just tried same with not existing folder and it shows same error. In provided tutorial they are using other directory path, maybe you have typed wrong path? theirs: `src/org/swig/simple`, yours: `src/com/example/swigbasicproject/swig`.